# How to identify Points Outside a 3D mesh in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mesh, large-data, points, boundary

I have two large data sets, one that is the outside of an object, and on that represents the fluid flow inside of the object. I am worried that with the mesh I have, some of the data might be mis-represented, or not modeled well, and is outside the first data set.

In Matlab, I used trisurf to create a mesh from the first data set and was curious if there was a way to check for points outside the mesh. Ive seen the 2D version of inpolygon, and some threshold functions, but the surface is not super regular and those don't really account for meshes. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: @Grant Miller
Here is the code used to plot the data, so the trisurf creats a mesh from data V, and I want to see if any points in D are outside of that range. Thanks!

figure(88), clf, trisurf(F,V(:,1),V(:,2),V(:,3));            title  ('Single hole Spray G1');
 xlabel('X (mm)');ylabel('Y (mm)');zlabel('Z (mm)');

hold on
figure(88), scatter3(D(:,1),D(:,2),D(:,3), .2,[1,0,0]);

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how what kind of data/format your object is defined as. If for example you have a Delaunay tetrahdralization/mesh of your object (if not you can use delaunay to create one from a point cloud), you can use the tsearchn function to determine if points are in/out of the object (mesh).

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tsearchn.html

Comment: the object boundary is a Delaunay mesh from a point cloud, but when I used tsearchn it gave me the following error: Error using tsearchn (line 25)
X and XI must have the same number of columns.       My data and the boundary points don't have the same amount of entries so what can I do? the function looks like it would be really useful if it can work with the different size of arrays.

Comment: X and XI must have the same number of columns (in your case 3 for 3D) but can have different number of rows (as in different number of points).